Is Hilt uses alpha version of Dagger’s KSP support under the hood?
In official Dagger documentation said:

Warning: Dagger’s KSP support is currently in alpha.

In Hilt release notes said:

Add KSP support to androidx.hilt.

So, my question is: is Hilt uses alpha version of Dagger’s KSP support under the hood?

Answer is here: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/4429#issuecomment-2333864098
Shortly:

Yes, the KSP support for both Dagger and Hilt are still in alpha.

